# C++ cannot add more variable to a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am currently running into a problem when doing with struct, I define a struct like the following:

```
typedef struct ObjCand
{
    // Initialize value for ObjCand
    ObjCand() : inFilter(false),
                match(false),
                inFrs(0),
                outFrs(0),
                Pos(Point(0, 0)), 
                filterPos(Point(0,0)),
                EKF(), 
                posList(POS_LIST_LENGTH),
                direction(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) {};
    bool            inFilter;
    bool            match;          
    int             inFrs;          
    int             outFrs;         
    Point           Pos;            
    Point           filterPos;  
    ExtendedKalmanFilter    EKF;
    vector<Point>   posList;
    Vec4f           direction;
} ObjCand;
```

Then I want to use a vector of this struct:

```
 vector< ObjCand > objCands;
```

The above part is fine, the problem is when I add one more variable in any type  to this struct and initialize it, it causes "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I run the program. There is no problem when compiling and running in Window, however it is a problem when I compile and running in Linux. 
I seem the problem is that the program does not get enough memory for the vector, so I try to reserve a large amount of memory for the vector. However, it does not work. 
I hope someone can show me what is the problem and how can I fix that.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think You should not Initialize the structure variable in Declaration...

Comment: There isn't nearly enough info here to say for sure, you might be using one of the types incorrectly, you might be blowing the stack. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How about putting together a short complete example that demonstrates the crash?

Comment: Are you trying to add a field that is huge, such as another class? You should not need to allocate memory for the vector, it does this for you.

Comment: Try storing pointers-to-ObjCand in your vector instead.

Comment: Perhaps one or more of `Point`, `ExtendedKalmanFilter`, or `Vec4f` do not have correct copy semantics implemented

Comment: Just curious: are you compiling in Linux with a Makefile?

Comment: Strangely enough, I just proposed the same thing in another question: Is this struct defined in a header? If yes, are you sure that all dependent source files are recompiled when you modify the definition in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Can you list out which of these typedefs (if any) are pointers ?